# Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, facebook-login

After adding the following dependencies

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.3.1'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.0.2'
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Program type already present: com.facebook.AccessTokenTacker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Removed the image and clarified the question

Comment: please share your complete build.gradle file

Comment: Downgrade version.